# How do you 301 redirect 404 errors on a Magento website?

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404, e-commerce

We have an e-commerce website built on the Magento platform at [vaperempire.com.au](https://vaperempire.com.au) and would like to automatically 301 redirect all 404 errors to the homepage. How would we go about doing this?

Thanks in advance to all those who help!

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php <--- Your home page
```

Try this on your .htaccess file. Carefull though because 404 responses are completly normal and let you diagnose bad urls on your webpage.

If there are only a few you can try this.

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage2.html http://www.yoursite.com/folder/
```